# DIV does not follow width of resized image

Tags: html, css

For some reason FireFox does not seem to resize the width of a floating div when the image is scaled on height and the width property is set to auto. It works as intended to in Chrome though.

[image: Rendering]

js-fiddle wont render it quite correctly so here is the code:

```
<STYLE>
div {
    border: solid 1px green;
}
.container {
   height:400px;
   width:300px;
}

.holder{
    border: solid 1px blue;
    float:right;
}
.resized {
    height:90%;
}
</STYLE>
<div class="container">
    <div class="holder">
        <img class="resized" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADYAAACPAgMAAADM7sDzAAAACVBMVEXMzMz+/v7///9Fv2/IAAAA7ElEQVRIS+3OMWrDQBAF0L9LNERbJRCDpNoGSaeY2tU2blK5SJVT6Ah7hCGkcOaUKRzv7gRsSBNM4t89+Mx84C9mgmAXazp9L2Qh7jPHRVpQYZQOnjMfLvLJ8t6ysZed/evMqtGZzbdcYVQmDGcZMPFzzZG3htHyMRiuLHvLO0ucp8ol/lYC0Oww63LkwHjVlLlilxDHU3mzeAYy94lQMe0JyKfcsibMkslrwiynstcDAZmkH54LGzQuFbagelUHz/XmW64vPWirb6qHIwltqOi5CwDkq+zSS03EaLjhoFI4WAaY8k/57VTNf5VPpH1Mhhj2avwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
    </div>
        <div>
            LOL, div.. Div Div Div Div Div Div Div Div Div Div Div 
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just tested on safari and chrome and it looks identical

Comment: personally, in this situation, I like to put my content into two containers like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fake060a/1/ , then you can just let the containers manage how your objects display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently due to an oddity in the quirks mode rendering. The solution was simply to force strict-HTML5 by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the beginning of the document, setting the image height to 100% and the height of "holder" to 90% (so that the image container gets the right size and the image get 100% of that height). Thanks to the [nice folks at Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1165595) for pointing this out

**the resulting head-part of the document:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<STYLE>
div {
    border: solid 1px green;
}
.container {
   height:400px;
   width:300px;
}

.holder{
    border: solid 1px blue;
    float:right;
    height: 90%;
}
.resized {
    height:100%;
}
```